# How to identify duplicate value in XML file using (c#)?

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I have XML file as below. I need to check for duplicate value inside  and if any duplicate found then I need to trigger a notification mail of its existence. Inner text of  must be unique for the whole XML file.

From the below file I have 2 value(inner text) of  are same. So how do I write the code to identify these duplicate and trigger a notification mail using (c#). sample code will be much appreciable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<JobsMapper>
    <Platform>
        <Platform_Data Name="GLP" ServerName="Lydsyd119" Input_Location="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FileWatcherIO\GLP\GLP\"/>
        <External_Delete_Request InstanceName="archive" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK Production Release\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\ExternalDeleteRequest\ExternalDelete\INPUT\"/>
        <Archival InstanceName="archive" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\Archive\BundleArchive\INPUT\"/>
        <Job InstanceName="0018" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\0018\MixedContent\INPUT\">
            <DPSI>0018</DPSI>
        </Job>
        <Job InstanceName="0019" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\0019\MixedContent\INPUT\">
            <DPSI>0019</DPSI>
        </Job>  
        <Job InstanceName="0CPN" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\0CPN\MixedContent\INPUT\">
            <DPSI>0CPN</DPSI>
        </Job>
        <Job InstanceName="0011" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\0011\MixedContent\INPUT\">
            <DPSI>0011</DPSI>
        </Job>  
        <Job InstanceName="0011" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\0011\MixedContent\INPUT\">
            <DPSI>0011</DPSI>
        </Job>      
        <Job InstanceName="000S" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\000S\MixedContent\INPUT\">
            <DPSI>000S</DPSI>
        </Job>
        <Job InstanceName="06JW" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\06JW\MixedContent\INPUT\">
            <DPSI>06JW</DPSI>
        </Job>
        <Job InstanceName="0N2Z" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\0N2Z\MixedContent\INPUT\">
            <DPSI>0N2Z</DPSI>
        </Job>  
        <Job InstanceName="0HNQ" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\0HNQ\MixedContent\INPUT\">
            <DPSI>0HNQ</DPSI>
        </Job>  
        <Job InstanceName="000Z" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\000Z\MixedContent\INPUT\">
            <DPSI>000Z</DPSI>
        </Job>
        <Job InstanceName="000W" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\000W\MixedContent\INPUT\">
            <DPSI>000W</DPSI>
        </Job>
        <Job InstanceName="0014" DestinationFolder="\\10.51.226.65\FTK_Production\IO\FabricationIO\0014\MixedContent\INPUT\">
            <DPSI>0014</DPSI>
        </Job>
        </Platform>
        </JobsMapper>
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of what you have tried so far and where you are having problems.

Comment: From the mentioned xml document I have  <DPSI>0011</DPSI> element  twice, whenever there is a duplicate record present in that particular xml file i need to trigger a mail. Sample code will be much appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will let you know how many nodes have duplicate values.

```
var result = XDocument.Parse(xml)
             .Descendants("DPSI")
             .GroupBy(x => x.Value)
             .Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```